# How To access Same Solution another Project Classes in MVC

Tags: asp.net

i  want to Access Same Solution another Project Classes in my Project.

Answer (score 1):

In the 'Solution Explorer' tree, expand the P2 project and then right-click the project and select 'Add Reference' from the menu.

On the 'Add Reference' dialog, select the 'Projects' tab and select your P1 project.

If you are using namespaces then you will need to import the namespaces for your P1 types by adding 'using' statements to your files in P2.

Note that the types in P1 that you wish to access directly must have a sufficient access level: typically this means they must be made public.

Comment: @DineshkumarD check your web config connection string name

Comment: @DavidG thank you so much for  format my answer post

Comment: @DineshkumarD can you Post connection strings code  and  Dbcontext  code ?